# delete all elements from array ruby and raise an error

Tags: ruby, arrays, error-handling

I am quite new to Ruby. A project I am working on is asking that I add elements to an array, which has a max capacity of 5.

Once the array is full (i.e. has five objects in it) I need to return an Error Message and clear the array. I have managed to implement both of these actions separately as can be seen in the code below, but I have been unable to combine them.

```
@capacity = 5

def full?
    array_count == @capacity 
end

def raise_error_clear
    raise 'Array is full' if full?  
end
```

I have managed to delete all elements in array if the max capacity of the array is reached.

```
 def raise_error_clear
    array.clear if full?
  end
```

I was hoping someone may be able to help and explain how to combine both these, so an error message is given and array is cleared at same time. I thought the following code would work but I am receiving an error.

```
 def raise_error_clear
    raise 'Airport is full' && array.clear if full?  
  end
```

Comment: The statements are checked in left-to-right order, that’s why an exception is thrown and an array stays untouched (the control flow is being passed to excepion handler whereever it is.) You might swap the instructions: `(array.clear && raise 'Array was full. Cleared.') if full?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put it in a if-condition.

```
def raise_error_clear
  if(full?)
    array.clear
    raise 'Airport is full'  
  end
end
```

Comment: An order matters, not the `if` operator style.

Comment: @mudasobwa doesn't it do the same as what OP is trying to do?